# Delete file after Dropbox transfer fails

Tags: java, dropbox

I try to use the official Dropbox API for uploading a zip file to my account. My project is a desktop application (standard Java). My code looks like this:

```
public void uploadZipFile(File file) throws Exception {
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
  try {
    getClient(accessToken).uploadFile("/" + file.getName(), DbxWriteMode.add(), file.length(), fis);
  } finally {
    fis.close();
  }
}

private DbxClient getClient(String accessToken) {
  DbxRequestConfig dbxRequestConfig = new DbxRequestConfig(Constants.APP_NAME, Locale.getDefault().toString());
  return new DbxClient(dbxRequestConfig, accessToken);
}
```

And I call it:

```
File zipFile = new File("C:\\Test\\MyFile.zip");
try {
  uploadZipFile(zipFile);
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The file is transferred without any problems but then I want to delete the file after synchronization:

```
File zipFile = new File("C:\\Test\\MyFile.zip");
try {
  uploadZipFile(zipFile);
  System.out.println(zipFile.delete());
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The file is transferred successfully again, but the file still exists in the local file system and the delete method returns false.

Comment: Try using the static method `java.nio.file.Files.delete(path)` it will throw an exception if any problems occur. `file.delete` only throws exception for permission issues.

Comment: Ok, I changed my code to Files.delete and the error is now: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process